# Best practice for controller method returns based on route

Tags: php, laravel

In `PossessionController` I have `store` method like this

```
public function store(StorePossessionRequest $r)
{
    $poss = Possession::create($r->validated());

    Log::quickStore(Possession::class, null, $poss);
    
    if (request()->url() != route('possessions.create'))
        return response(['message' => 'OK.'], 200);
    return redirect()->route('possessions');
}
```

The url condition is there because this method is accessible from two uris:

```
https://apk.test/possessions/create
https://apk.test/api/possessions/create
```

Is it a good practice to decide what will be returned based on uri, or should it be done differently?

Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I would implement separate namespaced controllers with your routes pointing to the respective controller. This allows for separation of concerns and is likely easier to maintain or extend in the future as you're not mixing web and api logic. If code repetition is a concern, consider extracting reusable logic to a service class and using the service container for dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (Request::wantsJson()) {
    // return JSON-formatted response
} else {
    // return HTML response
}
```